# How can I set the video bytes received from Firebase storage into a video player?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, firebase-storage, media-player, avkit

I trying to retrieve/load a video from Firebase storage to use those bytes into an iOS player, but im failing miserably. Im getting the right data from there (I have using debug and im getting right bytes that is 84611570) but I cannot use it with MPMoviePlayerController or AVPlayer cause both uses URL approaches. I have tried to give the path from the server but storage doesn't have a https sintax have some gs:// or something about it. I need some guidance about some approach cause I lost a lot of hours and didn't move on (loading 1%). My code is here below to someone check it. Any thoughts to how convert the data and put into a player ?

```
   func downloadVideo(filename:String){
    let downloadVideoReference = videoReference.child(filename)

    let dowloadTask = downloadVideoReference.getData(maxSize: 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, erro) in
        if data != nil {

            print(data)
            print(type(of: data))

     }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a HTTP URL to pass the data from Firebase Storage to the player, you'll want to [generate a download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#generate_a_download_url). A download URL is a URL that provides read-only access to the data to anyone (who has that URL), so you can set it on the player.

If you don't want to use a download URL (as this may be shared with other users who can then access the data without signing in), you'll have to find a player to which you can pass the data directly, instead of through a URL.

Comment: Thanks , I spent a lot of hours doing what probably would never work. Now I will try to find some way to do a custom player, cause I want put some comments and likes below the app. Either way , Up vote to you !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use on my SwiftUI Project in order to do this. Trust me I understand the frustration it took a couple hours of fiddling to get it to work.

```
let videoRef = storage.reference().child("video/\(uid).mp4")

let view = UIViewController()

videoRef.getData(maxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in

  if let error = error {

    print("ERROR: \(error)")
    print("Did not find video!")

  } else {

    let tmpFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("video").appendingPathExtension("mp4")
    do{
        try data!.write(to: tmpFileURL, options: [.atomic])
    }catch{
        print("error with video!")
    }

    let rect = CGRect(
        origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
        size: self.myuiscreen.bounds.size
    )
    self.player1 = AVPlayer(url: tmpFileURL)

    let controller = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player1)
    controller.player = self.player1
    self.player1!.isMuted = false

    do {
       try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
    } catch(let error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    self.player1!.play()

    controller.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    controller.frame = rect
    view.view.layer.addSublayer(controller)

    //Where the video repeats
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player1?.currentItem, queue: .main) { _ in
        self.player1!.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
        self.player1!.play()
    }
  }
}
```